# Firebase v1 HTTP api does not support nested JSON objects

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

**CURRENT SITUATION**

We send a POST request [Firebase legacy URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` to deliver notification JSON payload to our Android application. Our notification payload is a nested JSON object within a standard data. Our sample payload from Postman is given below

```
{
 "registration_ids": [
   "${registration_id}"],
   "priority":"HIGH", 
 "data": {
   "notification": {
     "title": "Notification Data Title From Postman",
     "body": "Notification Data Body From Postman",
     "imageurl": "https://d2x51gyc4ptf2q.cloudfront.net/content/uploads/2015/10/GettyImages-51205958-700x367.jpg"
   },
   "fcm_options": {
           "analytics_label": "postman"
     }
 }
}
```

The request headers are as follows:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`
Authorization: key={{server_key}}
```

In this example, the nested JSON object within the data object as shown below is used to successfully construct the notification.

```
"data": {
       "notification": {
         "title": "Notification Data Title From Postman",
         "body": "Notification Data Body From Postman",
         "imageurl": "https://d2x51gyc4ptf2q.cloudfront.net/content/uploads/2015/10/GettyImages-51205958-700x367.jpg"
       }
}
```

The server key is obtained from the Firebase console's project settings. This payload is successfully delivered to an Android app on an appropriate device to create a notification.

**PROBLEM**

We want to migrate to [Firebase v1 HTTP request APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1). I am attempting to use [OAuth2 Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#use_credentials_to_mint_access_tokens) to authenticate and deliver notifications to the Android device. The payload that I want to send through V1 api is given below

```
{
  "message": {
    "token": "${token}",
    "data": {
      "notification": {
        "title": "Notification Data Title From v1 API",
        "body": "Notification Data Body From v1 API",
        "imageurl": "https://d2x51gyc4ptf2q.cloudfront.net/content/uploads/2015/10/GettyImages-51205958-700x367.jpg",
        "extra_key": "extra_value"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "priority": "HIGH",
      "fcm_options": {
        "analytics_label": "Test_Command_line"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When we make a HTTP POST request to the v1 HTTP API, I get a 400 error with the following error message.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"title\" at 'message.data[3].value': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"body\" at 'message.data[3].value': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"imageurl\" at 'message.data[3].value': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"extra_key\" at 'message.data[3].value': Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "message.data[3].value",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"title\" at 'message.data[3].value': Cannot find field."
          },
          {
            "field": "message.data[3].value",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"body\" at 'message.data[3].value': Cannot find field."
          },
          {
            "field": "message.data[3].value",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"imageurl\" at 'message.data[3].value': Cannot find field."
          },
          {
            "field": "message.data[3].value",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"extra_key\" at 'message.data[3].value': Cannot find field."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But when the data payload is not nested as given below

```
"data": {
    "title": "Title that is not nested",
    "body": "Body that is not nested",
    "imageurl": "https://timedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/08/margot-robbie-beer-shower.jpg",
}
```

then I get a 200 OK response. The response body is given below

```
{
  "name": "projects/<project_id>/messages/<message_id>"
}
```

**DESIRED BEHAVIOUR**

I want to be able to deliver nested `data` payloads using Firebase v1 HTTP API to our Android app so that the notifications can be rendered. How can I achieve that given that I am getting errors when I send nested payloads? This is the program that I have been using to make HTTP requests. The program uses Google-API clients, FreeMarker, Firebase-Admin, and OKHttp.

```
public class FCMMessaging {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FirebaseMessagingException {

        // File was downloaded from Firebase console URL: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<project-id>/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk
        try(InputStream is =
                FCMMessaging.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("firebase-admin-service-account.json");) {

            GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential
                    .fromStream(is)
                    .createScoped(Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"));
            googleCredential.refreshToken();
            String bearerToken = googleCredential.getAccessToken();

            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();

            // Where do we load the notification payload templates from:
            cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(FCMMessaging.class, "");

            // Some other recommended settings:
            cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
            cfg.setLocale(Locale.US);
            cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.DEBUG_HANDLER);
            Map<String, Object> templateMap = new HashMap<>();
            templateMap.put("token",
                    "my-token-id");

            Template template = cfg.getTemplate("notification_payload.json");
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            template.process(templateMap, stringWriter);
            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(stringWriter.toString(), MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8"));
            Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project-id>/messages:send")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken).post(requestBody).build();

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
                System.out.println(response.body().string());
            }
        } catch (TemplateException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any luck with this? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @DerrylThomas Stringify the JSON payload, and sending is a key:value pair. Deserialise in your Firebase message handler.

Comment: Thanks! I figured this too in the meantime. I noticed that the payload received on the device seems exactly the same as it was with the old API which led me to the conclusion that FCM was internally stringifying all along.

Comment: Did you notice the same too? Or did you have to adapt anything in your app code to react to the new payload received from the HTTP V1 API?

Comment: I did not have to change in my Android code base, but my backend services had to update the template, and serialise the JSON object.

Comment: Great! Same here. Thanks anyways